# "Setting api_version is deprecated, only v2 will be supported" message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0, api-versioning

After running "rails console", I got the following message:

```
setting api_version is deprecated and will be removed shortly, only v2 is supported
```

Forgive my ignorance, but what exactly is being deprecated?

Comment: look inside your code if you are using the sentence "api_version" (grep -ri 'api_version' ./app, or something like that), just remove that line and you should be done

Comment: maybe there's a gem using that sentence, you should investigate your gems too